# Sqlite connected but information not transmitted

Tags: java, sqlite

I am a student and please try to help me and not brush me off. I hope that my code is understandable, I am trying to follow best practice.

"Edit" I changed what @Andrew suggested regarding the missing '. There are no error messages. The information is just not submitting

I am creating a registration form in java and connected it to my SQLITE database. (Got the message connection made). I have a couple of classes (files in java) and I will list below the "RegistrationForm class" that is creating the form and in which I added the 'getSelected' and named the String to match the SQL.
In the "Model class" I added the SQLITE connection and the columns field with the values.

```
`public class Model {
    String []pesonalInfo;
    public static void connect() {
    Connection conn = null;
    
        try {
            
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\myfek\\OneDrive\\Personal\\Gateshead "
                    + "College\\Project3\\ProjectATM.db";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("connection made");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String querie1= "INSERT INTO 'personalInfo'" + "(personal_title ,personal_first_name, "
                    + "personal_last_name,firstLAdd, secondLAdd, city, postcode, application_Company,"
                    + " application_Community, phone, date, month, year, email, password) "
                    + "VALUES (title, firstNameT, lastNameT, address1A, address2A, 'cityA', 'postCodeA',"
                    + "'areaCompany', 'areaCommunity', 'phoneA', 'dates', 'months', 'years', 'emailA', 'passwordT')";
            st.execute(querie1);
            conn.close();
            
         } catch (SQLException e) {  
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
            } finally {  
                try {  
                    if (conn != null) {  
                        conn.close();  
                    }  
                } catch (SQLException ex) {  
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());  
                }  
            }
        }
    
    
    
    public void regButtonactionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        connect();
    }

        

    }
`



public class RegistrationForm extends LogReg implements ActionListener{

    JFrame regInput = new JFrame();
    JLabel dob, titleL, companyL ;
    //private JButton regButton, cancelButton;
    JTextField  firstNameT, lastNameT, areaCompany, areaCommunity, address1A, address2A, cityA,
    postCodeA, emailA, phoneA, passwordT;
    

    String[] titleToChoose = { "Mr", "Mrs.", "Ms.", "Master", "Doctor" };
    JComboBox <String> title= new JComboBox<>(titleToChoose);
    
    String [] date = {
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "11", "12", "13", "14", "15","16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
            "21", "22", "23", "24", "25","26", "27", "28", "29", "30","31"
    };
    JComboBox <String> dates= new JComboBox<>(date);
    String month[]= {
            "Jan", "feb", "Mar", "Apr","May","Jun","July",
            "Aug","Sup", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    };
    JComboBox<String> months =  new JComboBox<>(month);
    String year[] = {
            "1970", "1971", "1972", "1973", "1974", "1975", "1976", "1977", "1978", "1979",
            "1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989",
            "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999",
            "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009"
    };
    JComboBox<String> years = new JComboBox<>(year);
    JButton regButton, cancelButton;

    public RegistrationForm(){
        JFrame regInput = new JFrame();
        regInput.setTitle("Registration Form");
        regInput.setLocation(200,10);

        titleL = new JLabel("Please enter your name");
        titleL.setSize(200,25);
        titleL.setLocation(80, 30);
        
        title.setSize(85,25);
        title.setLocation(110, 50);
        title.setSelectedIndex(0);

        firstNameT = new JTextField("First Name");
        firstNameT.setSize(200, 30);
        firstNameT.setLocation(200, 50);

        lastNameT= new JTextField("Last Name");
        lastNameT.setSize(200, 30);
        lastNameT.setLocation(400, 50);
        
        companyL= new JLabel("Please write below your organisation");
        companyL.setSize(500, 30);
        companyL.setLocation(90, 80);
        
        areaCompany = new JTextField("if Company");
        areaCompany.setSize(400, 30);
        areaCompany.setLocation(90, 110);
        
        areaCommunity= new JTextField("If Community");
        areaCommunity.setSize(400,30);
        areaCommunity.setLocation(90, 140);

        address1A= new JTextField("First line of address");
        address1A.setSize(300, 30);
        address1A.setLocation(90, 180);

        address2A = new JTextField("Second line of address");
        address2A.setSize(350, 30);
        address2A.setLocation(90, 220);

        cityA = new JTextField("City");
        cityA.setSize(250, 30);
        cityA.setLocation(90,250 );

        postCodeA = new JTextField("PostCode");
        postCodeA.setSize(250, 30);
        postCodeA.setLocation(350, 250);
        emailA= new JTextField("Email address");
        emailA.setSize(250, 30);
        emailA.setLocation(90, 300);
        passwordT = new JTextField("please enter your passowrd");
        passwordT.setSize(250, 30);
        passwordT.setLocation(400, 300);
        phoneA= new JTextField("Phone number");
        phoneA.setSize(200, 30);
        phoneA.setLocation(90, 340);
        dob = new JLabel("D.O.B.");
        dob.setFont(new Font("Ariel",Font.PLAIN,15));
        dob.setSize(100, 30);
        dob.setLocation(100, 390);

        dates.setSize(100, 20);
        dates.setLocation(180, 390);
        dates.setSelectedIndex(0);

        months.setSize(100, 20);
        months.setLocation(250, 390);
        months.setSelectedIndex(1);

        years.setSize(100, 20);
        years.setLocation(350, 390);
        years.setSelectedIndex(30);
        regButton = new JButton("Register");
        regButton.setText("Register");
        //regButton.setBounds(100, 300, 120, 150);
        //regButton.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);
        regButton.setSize(300, 40);
        regButton.setFont((new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD,20)));
        regButton.setLocation(200, 450);
        cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelButton.setSize(300, 40);
        cancelButton.setFont((new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD,20)));
        cancelButton.setLocation(525,450);
        regInput.getContentPane();
        regInput.add(titleL);
        regInput.add(title);
        regInput.add(firstNameT);
        regInput.add(lastNameT);
        regInput.add(areaCommunity);
        regInput.add(areaCompany);
        regInput.add(companyL);
        regInput.add(address1A);
        regInput.add(address2A);
        regInput.add(cityA);
        regInput.add(postCodeA);
        regInput.add(phoneA);
        regInput.add(emailA);
        regInput.add(passwordT);
        regInput.add(dob);
        regInput.add(dates);
        regInput.add(months);
        regInput.add(years);
        regInput.add(regButton);
        regInput.add(cancelButton);
        regInput.setBounds(300, 90, 900, 600);
        regInput.setLayout(null);
        regInput.setResizable(false);
        regInput.setVisible(true);
        

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new RegistrationForm();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getSource()==registerButton) {
            //regInput.setVisible(true);
            String personal_title = (String) title.getSelectedItem();
            String personal_first_name = firstNameT.getSelectedText();
            String personal_last_name = lastNameT.getSelectedText();
            String firstLAdd = address1A.getSelectedText();
            String secondLAdd= address2A.getSelectedText();
            String city = cityA.getSelectedText();
            String postcode = postCodeA.getSelectedText();
            String application_Company = areaCompany.getSelectedText(); 
            String application_Community = areaCommunity.getSelectedText();
            String phone = phoneA.getSelectedText(); 
            String date= (String) dates.getSelectedItem();
            String month = (String) months.getSelectedItem();
            String year = (String) years.getSelectedItem(); 
            String email = emailA.getSelectedText();
            String password = passwordT.getSelectedText(); 
            //connect(); I tried this
            

        }else if(e.getSource()==loginButton) {
            System.out.println("Login");
            }
        }
        

    }
```

Comment: [The Oracle tutorial page on Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) might have some useful information for you.

Comment: Just an observation: where you have `"VALUES (title, ...`, I assume that should be `"VALUES ('title', ...` and so on. The values needs to be in single quotes if you are hard-coding them all in the SQL statement. (Also, [edit] your question to show the full error message.)

Comment: @andrewJames. Thank you. 
I edited the question and I realised that the "if" statement is not responding. I did that by asking System.out.println. and got no reply. Can you see what is wrong with my if statement (registrationForm) please?

Comment: The code in your question still shows an invalid SQL statement (as per my previous comment) - one that should throw a `SQLException` with an error message. I don't know why you are not apparently seeing any error message for that.

Comment: I am using Eclipse as the IDE and I fixed the if statement for system print. I also intentionally misspelled one of the columns in the Model class and got a message that they cannot find the column. When I fixed t, I have gotten no messages but at the end of the day, it just doesn't record anything @andrewJames

Comment: OK, but show us the code you are actually running. What do you mean by "it doesn't record anything"? Are you saying the INSERT does not insert any data into the table? If so, how do you know that?

Answer (score 0):

I redone the if Statement below. I first needed to initialise `prepareStatment` which I named `pst`. Please see code below

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e1) {
    if (e1.getSource() == regButton) {
        regInput.dispose();  
        Connection con = Model.connect();
        
        String query = "insert into registrationAtm values(?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        

        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(2,((String) title.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            pst.setString(3, firstNameT.getText());
            pst.setString(4, lastNameT.getText());
            pst.setString(5, addT.getText());
            pst.setString(6, cityT.getText());
            pst.setString(7, postcodeT.getText());
            pst.setInt(8, Integer.parseInt((String) dates.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            pst.setString(9, (String) months.getSelectedItem());
            pst.setInt(10, Integer.parseInt((String) years.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            pst.setString(11, emailT.getText());
            pst.setString(12, passwordT.getText());
            
            pst.execute();
            
            String query2 = "insert into detailsAtm values (?,?)"; 
            pst2 = con.prepareStatement(query2);
            pst2.setString(2, companyText.getText());
            pst2.setString(3, communityText.getText());
            pst2.execute();
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } else if (e1.getSource() == cancelButton) {
        System.out.print("Cancel");

    }
}
```